# Compiling rust-bindgen on Ubuntu

Tags: rust

Did anybody manage to compile [rust-bindgen](https://github.com/crabtw/rust-bindgen) on Ubuntu 14.04? I don't know, for example, how to statically build and link to `libclang.so`. I use rust-nightly.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to use the macro or the executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The following only sets up the executable, not the macro.*

I assume you have `git` and `rustc` setup correctly. bindgen will need a fairly recent rustc to compile.

Clone the repository:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/crabtw/rust-bindgen
$ cd rust-bindgen
```

Build the library:

```
$ rustc lib.rs
```

Build the wrapping executable, linking with the previously built library:

```sh
$ rustc -L . bindgen.rs
```

Run the executable, in this case on the Xlib headers:

```sh
$ ./bindgen -l xlib -o xlib.rs /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h
```

The executable may segfault if libclang is setup wrong. In that case, preload the correct library and pass the right options to clang:

```sh
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libclang.so ./bindgen -I /usr/lib/clang/3.4.2/include -l xlib -o xlib.rs /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h
```

To install the correct version of clang, you may try to install [libclang-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/precise/libclang-dev).

Comment: Hi, I followed your instructions I have libclang3.4-dev installed. I did get the following error: `macro.rs:152                 let expr = cx.expand_expr(parser.parse_expr());
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: linking with cc failed: exit code: 1
` and `note: /usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: cannot find -lclang
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: aborting due to previous error
` Sorry I can't post the whole error message plus warnings due to the size limit on comments.

Comment: The above are the error messages I did get, while trying to compile lib.rs.

Comment: I thin the problem has to do with the dynamically compiled preinstalled libclang-dev: Here are the error messages I get: error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1  note: /usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: cannot find -lclang
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: aborting due to previous error